# Equally spaced fixed size buttons Android

Tags: java, android, xml, button

I have this xml document. I want to have these 93 by 93px button images equally spaced. At the moment the weight setting is making them stretch and hug each other so there are no spaces. But if I set weight to 0 they do the same hugging each other but fill up about half of the screen.

This is for landscape orientation by the way.

```
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent">
   <Button 
    android:background="@drawable/a" 
    android:layout_height="93px" 
    android:id="@+id/a"
    android:layout_width="93px" 
    android:layout_weight="1" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dip" 
    android:layout_marginTop="30dip"/>
  <Button 
    android:background="@drawable/b" 
    android:layout_height="93px" 
    android:id="@+id/b"
    android:layout_width="93px" 
    android:layout_weight="1"  
    android:layout_marginTop="30dip"/>

  <Button 
    android:background="@drawable/c" 
    android:layout_height="93px" 
    android:id="@+id/c" 
    android:layout_weight="1" 
    android:layout_width="93px"  
    android:layout_marginTop="30dip"/>
  <Button 
    android:background="@drawable/d" 
    android:layout_height="93px" 
    android:id="@+id/d"
    android:layout_width="93px" 
    android:layout_weight="1" 
    android:layout_marginRight="20dip" 
    android:layout_marginTop="30dip" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LinearLayout` does not have an intrinsic notion of "equal spacing". You might consider using a layout designed for a "dashboard", such as https://gist.github.com/882650.

Comment: thanks that looks perfect for this and another layout issue I have. If you could take a minute to briefly explain how to implement this that would be great. Once I've put that file into my apk what should I do from there?

Comment: @Max: See http://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/browse/android/res/layout/fragment_dashboard.xml

Comment: The first link you sent me I should just save as com.google.android.apps.iosched.ui.widget with all my other packages under scr correct?

Comment: @Max: Well, you need to be consistent. If you leave the package in the Java class alone, it will need to go into `src/com/google/android/apps/iosched/ui/widget/` in your project, and you would refer to it as `com.google.android.apps.iosched.ui.widget.DashboardLayout` in your layout XML. If you prefer, you can change the Java package, but you will need to change the directory and layout to match.

Answer (score 4):

The solution is simple.

You have to keep each button into individual linear layout and keep weight=1 for each Linear Layout. Now buttons will be equally spaced, no matter whatever the resolution or orientation is.

EX:-

```
      <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent">
      <LinearLayout android:id=@+id/Button1Parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android_width="wrap_content" android:weight="1" gravity="center">  
       <Button 
        android:background="@drawable/a" 
        android:layout_height="93px" 
        android:id="@+id/takequiz"
        android:layout_width="93px" 
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dip" 
        android:layout_marginTop="30dip"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout android:id=@+id/Button2Parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android_width="wrap_content" android:weight="1" gravity="center">
      <Button 
        android:background="@drawable/b" 
        android:layout_height="93px" 
        android:id="@+id/random"
        android:layout_width="93px" 
        android:layout_weight="1"  
        android:layout_marginTop="30dip"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout android:id=@+id/Button3Parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android_width="wrap_content" android:weight="1" gravity="center">

      <Button 
        android:background="@drawable/c" 
        android:layout_height="93px" 
        android:id="@+id/search" 
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:layout_width="93px"  
        android:layout_marginTop="30dip"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout android:id=@+id/Button4Parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android_width="wrap_content" android:weight="1" gravity="center">

      <Button 
        android:background="@drawable/d" 
        android:layout_height="93px" 
        android:id="@+id/browse"
        android:layout_width="93px" 
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:layout_marginRight="20dip" 
        android:layout_marginTop="30dip" />
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout01"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_height="93px"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        ></Button>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_height="93px"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        ></Button>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/btn3"
            android:layout_height="93px"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        ></Button>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/btn4"
            android:layout_height="93px"
            android:layout_weight="1"
        ></Button>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried updating your current LinearLayout to the following and had the square evenly spaced buttons - but they do not fit on my emulator's screen.  So in my case it is the margins that you had set on the left and right that were squishing them in.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/LinearLayout" 
   android:layout_height ="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width  ="fill_parent" 
   android:orientation   ="horizontal"
   android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

   <Button  
    android:id="@+id/takequiz"  
    android:text="take quiz"
    android:layout_height="93px"
    android:layout_width ="93px" 
    android:layout_marginTop ="30dip"/>

  <Button 
    android:id="@+id/random" 
    android:text="random"
    android:layout_height="93px" 
    android:layout_width ="93px" 
    android:layout_marginTop="30dip"/>

  <Button 
    android:id="@+id/search" 
    android:text="search"
    android:layout_height="93px"
    android:layout_width="93px" 
    android:layout_marginTop="30dip"/>

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/browse"
    android:text="browse"
    android:layout_height="93px" 
    android:layout_width="93px" 
    android:layout_marginTop="30dip" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Had you considered 2 rows?  I have done a similar thing for a sound board type of app using TableLayout.  Although these days I tend to use RelativeLayout more.  Here is the table code.

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/LinearLayout" 
   android:layout_height ="fill_parent"
   android:layout_width  ="fill_parent" >
   <TableRow
      android:layout_height ="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width  ="fill_parent" 
      android:gravity       ="center">    
       <Button  
        android:id  ="@+id/takequiz"  
        android:text="take quiz"
        android:layout_height="93px"
        android:layout_width ="93px" />    
      <Button 
        android:id  ="@+id/random" 
        android:text="random"
        android:layout_height="93px" 
        android:layout_width ="93px" />
    </TableRow> 
    <TableRow
      android:layout_height ="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width  ="fill_parent" 
      android:gravity       ="center">    
        <Button 
          android:id  ="@+id/search" 
          android:text="search"
          android:layout_height="93px"
          android:layout_width ="93px" />       
        <Button
          android:id  ="@+id/browse"
          android:text="browse"
          android:layout_height="93px" 
          android:layout_width ="93px"  />
    </TableRow>
 </TableLayout>
```

Comment: it didnt fit your screen? What size did you use? And were you in landscape orentation? If so I might need to rethink the layout.

Answer (score 0):

Just set a margin left or margin right to any 1 of the buttons